# MDI Parent Not Keeping Form In Client Area

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

i am trying to create a MDI applications with winforms,

the form design is borderless and i have a mainmenu strip,
when i maximize the child it appears to be out of the client area,
it blocks the main menustrip, and the scroll bars do not activate,
I have read that borderless forms do not work properly as mdi parents, but I am having this issue even with the property set to single/sizeable

i am going for a look similar to google chrome but it appears i have to keep the titlebar, i want the biggest workspace possible.

i can programmatically reduce the height of the child and move it down by the height of the menu strip but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

My parent settings are as follows

```
IsMdiContainer = true
```

and I am launching the form in this manner

```
X10d_Suite.cfBinaryEditor xForm = new X10d_Suite.cfBinaryEditor();

xForm.TopLevel = false;
xForm.Parent = this;
xForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Controls.Add(xForm);
xForm.Show();
```

I want the child to remain under the menustrip.  and scrollbars to activate when
a form is going out the visible client area.

[image: Heres a picture of the form,]

Comment: I THINK the correct way is `xForm.MdiParent = this;` for multiple document interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Charles May,

`xForm.MdiParent = this;` instead of `xForm.Parent = this;` fixed it.